# select the Max record for each device, which was recorded on 10th day

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a table tblActiveList which has ‘DeviceID’ and ‘TimeAdded’ columns and another table tblActiveBladeLive with DeviceID, RecordedDate and Angle columns
How I can select the Max Angle for each device, which was recorded on 10th day (each device can have multiple angles on any day)?

Here is my query to select 10th Day of Device added

```
Select DeviceID, TimeAdded, TimeAdded+10 as '10TH_Day' from tblActiveList

DeviceID    TimeAdded                 10TH_Day
BL000343    2018-08-08 15:09:54.483   2018-08-18 15:09:54.483
BL000247    2018-08-08 17:03:57.593   2018-08-18 17:03:57.593
```

Here is 2nd table with all the angles for several months from Day device added.

```
Select DeviceID, RecordedDate, Angle from tblActiveBladeLive

DeviceID    RecordedDate            Angle
BL000343    2018-08-15 23:55:13.000 11.50
BL000343    2018-08-16 22:54:58.000 12.55
BL000343    2018-08-16 21:54:58.000 12.55
BL000343    2018-08-17 23:54:59.000 13.15
BL000343    2018-08-18 05:54:59.000 15.15
BL000343    2018-08-18 01:54:59.000 13.15
BL000247    2018-08-17 03:44:57.000 15.78
BL000247    2018-08-18 06:46:41.000 15.05
BL000247    2018-08-17 11:46:56.000 15.05
BL000247    2018-08-18 05:46:41.000 14.05
```

Here are the records which need to be selected

```
DeviceID    RecordedDate            Angle
BL000343    2018-08-18 05:54:59.000 15.15
BL000247    2018-08-18 06:46:41.000 15.05
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: which db you are effectively using  ?.. date time function are specific for each db brand  (SQL is a query language and not a db name)

Comment: JOIN the tables, on same deviceid and date parts of TimeAdded + 10 = RecordedDate.

Comment: What is your exact problem? How far have you got with your query? Where are you stuck? What problem are you facing? And as scaisEdge said: we need the DBMS you are using (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, ...).

Comment: I don't understand the data.  Is the time component important?  How are multiple readings on the same date handled? Your sample data has no readings on the time added date.  What if there are no readings on the 10th day?

Comment: What to do when a device has the same maximum angle twice on the tenth day? Show both rows? Show one row only? If one row only, which?

Comment: I am using sql server 2017, and if there is no Angle on 10th day just show null for that device. If the device has the same maximum angle twice on the tenth day on same time show only one row any one row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
SELECT A.DeviceID, MAX(RecordedDate) AS RecordedDate, A.Angle
FROM (SELECT tblActiveList.DeviceID, CONVERT(date,DATEADD(d,10,TimeAdded)) AS Day10, MAX(Angle) AS Angle
        FROM tblActiveList
            LEFT JOIN tblActiveBladeLive ON tblActiveList.DeviceID=tblActiveBladeLive.DeviceID AND CONVERT(date,DATEADD(d,10,TimeAdded))=CONVERT(date,RecordedDate)
        GROUP BY tblActiveList.DeviceID, TimeAdded) A
    LEFT JOIN tblActiveBladeLive B ON A.DeviceID=B.DeviceID AND A.Angle=B.Angle AND Day10=CONVERT(date,RecordedDate)
GROUP BY A.DeviceID, A.Angle
```

This was written without a testing environment so typos and bugs may exist. It is easy to get the max angle on the 10th day. The hard part is then getting the timestamp corresponding to it. If you don't care about the time part and only the date part in the end result it can get much simpler:

```
SELECT tblActiveList.DeviceID, CONVERT(date,DATEADD(d,10,TimeAdded)) AS Day10, MAX(Angle) AS Angle
FROM tblActiveList
    LEFT JOIN tblActiveBladeLive ON tblActiveList.DeviceID=tblActiveBladeLive.DeviceID AND CONVERT(date,DATEADD(d,10,TimeAdded))=CONVERT(date,RecordedDate)
GROUP BY tblActiveList.DeviceID, TimeAdded
```

Comment: Spot On! Thanks a lot that's exactly what I was looking for. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Yes as long as it selects the max angle(which it is selecting) time part is not important.

Answer (score 0):

I am kind of confused about your data and what you are looking for. What you are going to need to do is use a `JOIN`, a CTE, probably `GROUP BY` at least once. Most likely a correlated subquery. If you can rephrase your question a little better, that would help. Also add which SQL engine you are using if you know.

Answer (score 0):

Edited 1. There was an issue.

try this. It looks like the same approach is mentioned above, but maybe it can be useful:

```
WITH device_10thDay as
(
Select 
    DeviceID, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(day, 10, TimeAdded), 103) as 'Tenth_Day' 
from tblActiveList
)

Select 
    tenDays.DeviceID, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), RecordedDate, 103) as RecordedDate, 
    MAX(Angle) as Angle
from device_10thDay tenDays 
left JOIN tblActiveBladeLive tbl on tenDays.DeviceID = tbl.DeviceID and tenDays.Tenth_Day = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), RecordedDate, 103) 
group by 
    tenDays.DeviceID, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), RecordedDate, 103)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    DeviceID 
,   RecordedDate
,   Angle
FROM (
SELECT 
    tab.DeviceID
,   tab.RecordedDate
,   tab.Angle
,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tab.DeviceID ORDER BY RecordedDate DESC) MaxRN  
FROM @tblActiveBladeLive tab
LEFT JOIN  @tblActive ta 
    ON ta.DeviceID = tab.DeviceID 
    AND ta.TimeAdded <= tab.RecordedDate 
    AND CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 10,CAST(TimeAdded AS DATE) ) AS DATETIME) + ' 23:59:59' >= tab.RecordedDate 
) D
WHERE 
    MaxRN = 1
```

Note :

```
CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 10,CAST(TimeAdded AS DATE) ) AS DATETIME) + ' 23:59:59'
```

Casting TimeAdded to Date and added 10 days then giving it time 23:59:59 to make sure that we will get all records in the 10th day.

you can update tblActiveList table with the correct dates. This would make things more efficient and easier to work with for long-term use.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe your accepted answer will handle ties when there are multiple angle readings for the same date. Here is a typical approach using row numbering.

```
with MaxAngle as (
    select DeviceID, RecordedDate, Angle,
        row_number() over
            (partition by DeviceID, cast(RecordedDate as date) order by Angle desc) as rn
    from tblActiveBladeLive
)
select *
from tblActiveList as l left outer join MaxAngle as a
    on      a.DeviceID = l.DeviceID
        and cast(dateadd(day, 10, a.TimeAdded) as date) = cast(l.RecordedDate as date)
        and a.rn = 1;
```

Comment: Your answer is also correct the difference between your and SunKnight0 answer is that you select max angle value from 10th day whereas SunKnight0 selects angle from 10th day which was recorded last on that day and by chance both works exactly same for me because Max angle from the 10th day will be recorded last. I hope I have not created more confusion :)

Comment: @ThirdPartyAuth Ok, I thought you did want max angle. It's a simple matter of changing to `order by RecordedDate desc` to accomplish that. Fundamentally the same problem!

Comment: Actually my solution also selects max angle regardless of whether it was last or not. It then selects the max timestamp out of those that correspond to the max angle. You just have to read it `in to out` rather than `top to bottom` to understand how it works.

Comment: Yeah, I should have thrown in another sort for the time to handle ties on angle. But I did overlook the outer `group by`.